# Using Postgres, I want a timestamp in a specific format in a string in the query

Tags: postgresql

Here is the query I would like

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'shop_ean_2016_06_12';
```

but "2016_06_12" in the query should be yesterday.
I know "NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL" but I want to use it in the table name comparison.

Thank you for any way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name ='shop_ean_' || to_char(now() - interval '1 day','YYYY_MM_DD');
```